# Switch battery usage off when jack 3.5mm is not inserted

Tags: connector, batteries, toggle-switch

I have an ongoing project where I'm using a condenser microphone to record various stuff, it's powered by a CR2032 battery and the output of the microphone is directed to a TRRS jack connector (3.5mm), and I'm looking for a way to save the battery life since it's for a light usage (around an hour per week, and letting the battery power the microphone non stop would drain the battery in about a week).

Kinda like a switch off battery when jack is not inserted.

But to be honest, I'm a bit lost on that part.

My current schematic is the following one :

[image]

I hope someone can guide me to some ressources or answer, and I hope my post is comprehensive !

Answer (score 0):

You can buy 3.5mm jacks that include built-in switch(es).  They will have separate connections for this switch, so you can wire your battery up through it.

There are three common types.  One where a switch is opened when the plug is inserted, on where the switch closes when the plug is inserted, and ones that have both.

The easiest would be to use the type where a contact is made when the plug is inserted.  Just wire up on of the leads to your battery through this switch.

Get one with an isolated normally-open switch.  Something like this:

[image]

Disconnect one side of your battery, and hook up the two ends to pins 5 and 6 and you are good to go.

Comment: I see ! That would be perfect indeed !

The exception being that I need a switch on the Ring 2 (which is the GND) of a TRRS-compatible connector, and for now, I only found one and it's SMD, the SJ-43617-SMT-TR available on Mouser.

Would you happen to know one in THT form ? That would be best suitable for me, and I can't seem to find one sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your goal is accomplished by default.
This is a mono mic? No DC current flows from battery to microphone that is not inserted into the jack. So simply unplug the microphone when not in use. The very simplest jack is sufficient:
[image: simple jack]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqAmQh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It looks like the jack is on the other side of the battery, and the battery is constantly connected to the microphone.

Comment: @evildemonic Guess I'm guilty of not including schematic that so often happens here... have added one that might work.

Comment: It's a mono mic, yes, but I don't understand how your schematic would prevent the battery from powering the mic non stop, maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: As @evildemonic has suggested, we differ where the battery powers the mic. You want to place the battery at the microphone end of the plug, while I'm suggesting to place the battery (and resistor) on *the other side* of the jack, where the audio is being amplified. Doing it this way, pulling the plug cuts battery drain to zero.

Comment: Except if I'm mistaken, the jack doesn't have an "other side", on standard connector, the tip is the + and only have one pin, no switch, so placing the battery on the schematic on one side or the other would'nt change the result, right ?